# Is compiling php 5.6 with these errors ok?

Tags: php, make

I am compiling php 5.6 with the following:

```
sudo ./configure  '--with-apxs2' '--disable-cgi' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-readline' '--with-zlib' '--with-openssl' '--with-curl' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-soap' '--enable-wddx' '--with-tidy' '--with-jpeg-dir' '--with-png-dir' '--with-gd' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-freetype-dir' '--with-libxml-dir' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-config-file-path=/etc/httpd/conf' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-opcache' '--prefix=/usr/local/php-5.6.4'
```

And get the following after running configure, make and then make test, which i dont know if its same to processeed with make install. Really hoping someone clarify to me that this is something i should correct or if its OK as-is. THANKS!

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :   35
Exts tested     :   44
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests : 13482             10366
Tests skipped   : 3116 ( 23.1%) --------
Tests warned    :    5 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   28 (  0.2%) (  0.3%)
Expected fail   :   32 (  0.2%) (  0.3%)
Tests passed    : 10301 ( 76.4%) ( 99.4%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :  902 seconds
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
EXPECTED FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Test open_basedir configuration [tests/security/open_basedir_linkinfo.phpt]
XFAIL REASON: BUG: open_basedir cannot delete symlink to prohibited file.
See             also
bugs 48111 and 52176.
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_008.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Discussion:   http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members - 2 [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_009.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #63336 (invalid E_NOTICE error occur) [Zend/tests/bug63336.phpt]  XFAIL  REASON: Bug is not fixed yet
Bug #64896 (Segfault with gc_collect_cycles using unserialize on certain objects) [Zend/tests/bug64896.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: We can not fix this bug without a significant (performace slow down) change to gc
Initial value of static var in method depends on the include time of the class definition [Zend/tests/method_static_var.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Maybe not a bug
DateTime::add() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
RFC: DateTime and Daylight Saving Time Transitions (zone type 3, bd2) [ext/date/tests/rfc-datetime_and_daylight_saving_time-type3-bd2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Still not quite right
RFC: DateTime and Daylight Saving Time Transitions (zone type 3, fs) [ext/date/tests/rfc-datetime_and_daylight_saving_time-type3-fs.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Still not quite right
Bug #67296 (filter_input doesn't validate variables) [ext/filter/tests/bug49184.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #49184
zend multibyte (7) [ext/mbstring/tests/zend_multibyte-07.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66582
zend multibyte (9) [ext/mbstring/tests/zend_multibyte-09.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66582
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
RFC 2144 test vectors for CAST-128 in ECB mode (bug #62102) [ext/mcrypt/tests/bug62102_rfc2144.phpt]
#46127, openssl_sign/verify: accept different algos [ext/openssl/tests/bug46127.phpt]
Bug #48182: ssl handshake fails during asynchronous socket connection [ext/openssl/tests/bug48182.phpt]
Bug #54992: Stream not closed and error not returned when SSL CN_match fails [ext/openssl/tests/bug54992.phpt]
Bug #65538: SSL context "cafile" supports stream wrappers [ext/openssl/tests/bug65538_001.phpt]
Bug #65538: SSL context "cafile" supports phar wrapper [ext/openssl/tests/bug65538_003.phpt]
Bug #65729: CN_match gives false positive when wildcard is used [ext/openssl/tests/bug65729.phpt] 
capture_peer_cert context captures on verify failure [ext/openssl/tests/capture_peer_cert_001.phpt]
Testing peer fingerprint on connection [ext/openssl/tests/openssl_peer_fingerprint.phpt]
Peer verification enabled for client streams [ext/openssl/tests/peer_verification.phpt]
Peer verification matches SAN names [ext/openssl/tests/san_peer_matching.phpt]
Capture SSL session meta array in stream context [ext/openssl/tests/session_meta_capture.phpt]
sni_server [ext/openssl/tests/sni_server.phpt]
Basic bitwise stream crypto context flag assignment [ext/openssl/tests/stream_crypto_flags_001.phpt]
TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 bitwise stream crypto flag assignment [ext/openssl/tests/stream_crypto_flags_002.phpt]
Server bitwise stream crypto flag assignment [ext/openssl/tests/stream_crypto_flags_003.phpt]
Specific protocol method specification [ext/openssl/tests/stream_crypto_flags_004.phpt]
TLS server rate-limits client-initiated renegotiation [ext/openssl/tests/stream_server_reneg_limit.phpt]
Verify host name by default in client transfers [ext/openssl/tests/stream_verify_peer_name_001.phpt]
Allow host name mismatch when "verify_host" disabled [ext/openssl/tests/stream_verify_peer_name_002.phpt]
Host name mismatch triggers error [ext/openssl/tests/stream_verify_peer_name_003.phpt]
Specific crypto method for ssl:// transports. [ext/openssl/tests/streams_crypto_method.phpt]
tlsv1.0 stream wrapper [ext/openssl/tests/tlsv1.0_wrapper.phpt]
tlsv1.1 stream wrapper [ext/openssl/tests/tlsv1.1_wrapper.phpt]
tlsv1.2 stream wrapper [ext/openssl/tests/tlsv1.2_wrapper.phpt]
Bug #51800 proc_open on Windows hangs forever, the right way to do it [ext/standard/tests/streams/proc_open_bug51800_right.phpt]
Bug #51800 proc_open on Windows hangs forever, the right way to do it with more data [ext/standard/tests/streams/proc_open_bug51800_right2.phpt]
CLI -a and readline [sapi/cli/tests/016.phpt]
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
WARNED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
zend multibyte (2) [ext/mbstring/tests/zend_multibyte-02.phpt] (warn: XFAIL section but test passes)
zend multibyte (6) [ext/mbstring/tests/zend_multibyte-06.phpt] (warn: XFAIL section but test passes)
zend multibyte (8) [ext/mbstring/tests/zend_multibyte-08.phpt] (warn: XFAIL section but test passes)
zend multibyte (10) [ext/mbstring/tests/zend_multibyte-10.phpt] (warn: XFAIL section but test passes)
zend multibyte (11) [ext/mbstring/tests/zend_multibyte-11.phpt] (warn: XFAIL section but test passes)
=====================================================================
```

Comment: On exactly what sort of system are you compiling PHP? And more importantly, why are you doing this at all?

Comment: upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6 on centos7.

Comment: Don't bother with compiling it yourself. Just use [remi's](http://rpms.remirepo.net/) packages.

Comment: You can also get 5.6 from [IUS](https://iuscommunity.org/pages/About.html).

Comment: You could, but since Remi packages the official Red Hat packages also, and the IUS packages are ... weird...

Comment: so of 10 or 12 servers i literally have 2 left to do. All the rest built fine w/o issue and the desire would to have all be built the same way for consistency. Would proceeding with the following errors be problematic?